# How to UploadFile to web server without creating a file?

Tags: c#, .net, webclient

I have to upload dynamically created data file to web server. 
One way to do that is to create a temporary file dump data to that file, and then use WebClient.UploadFile to do work. But how to do that without creating a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [`WebClient.UploadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tdbbwh0a.aspx), which takes a byte array, or [`UploadString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y.aspx), which takes a string.

Comment: Yes, but upload is different. 
It does not create file info:

Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------8cc6c7ba6182136